# Sum every nth column with N/As potentially among the data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to sum every nth (13) column and am using the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN(W3:ZJ3)-COLUMN(W3)+1,13)=1),W3:ZJ3)
```

The issue I'm running into is that within my range of W3:ZJ3, there are N/As and I can't figure out how to get sumproduct to ignore those values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to a SUM array formula with an IF:

```
=SUM(IF((MOD(COLUMN(W3:ZJ3)-COLUMN(W3)+1,13)=1)*(ISNUMBER(W3:ZJ3)),W3:ZJ3))
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Now if `W3:ZJ3` is not a number it will be omitted from the sum.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I hadn't thought to use an array formula at all

Comment: When the question is 15 minutes old you will be able to mark as correct, please do so.